# How to set the position of the palette when use CreatePalette[]

Tags: programming

When using `CreatePalette[]`, the palette created always shows up on the upper left corner. Is there a way to make it show up at the center of the screen, just like what `CreateDialog[]` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the preset value of the [`WindowMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WindowMargins.html) option to `Automatic`. Example:

```
 CreatePalette[Row[PasteButton /@ ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]]], 
 WindowMargins -> Automatic, WindowTitle -> "Letters"];
```