# How can I programmatically specify the positioning of a window at the time of its creation?

Tags: notebooks

```
CreateDocument[{}, WindowSize -> {100, 100}]
```

always centers the new window.

Comment: `HammingWindow[t-position]`

Comment: @Rojo German pun: I'm the viper. I've come to vipe your vindows.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45288/5478)

Answer (score 5):

To make the offset from the top left corner of the screen `10` down and `100` to the right, do this:

```
CreateDocument[{}, WindowSize -> {100, 100}, 
  WindowMargins -> {{100, Automatic}, {Automatic, 10}}]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jens.  Problem solved.  (By the way, I did my graduate work at UO in 1971.)